# ProgressBar jQuery don't work

Tags: jquery, css

hi i've a project that include some progress bar.
 http://jsfiddle.net/V5Sgs/5/ 

I'm a newbie of jQuery, but anyway i would set the .bar width with the value taken from the css.

```
{width: cssWidth }
```

or

```
{width: progressBarWidth }
```

On jsfiddle work correctly but when i use my project with the same code the animation don't work and the bar remains static.
what could be the matter?

Comment: show us the `<head>` section of your page - you might not be including jquery correctly

Comment: did you check your jquery included properly in html?.

Comment: if you are using chrome, right click and click "inspect element". If you see red cross at bottom right of inspect element, you probably missing something. Find it and rectify it

Comment: i've added the head code http://jsfiddle.net/V5Sgs/6/

Answer (score 0):

code seems fine, may be the problem of jquery file not included or may be jquery conflict with other javascript library. Please check jquery file